# A signal as a sum of sinusoids

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I am doing some signal processing revision from my undergraduate studies and I came by an interesting fact that the book I am reading states.

> Any signal can be written as the sum of a constant term and a sequence of sinusoids. That is, $x(t) = A_0 + \sum_k A_kcos(2\pi f_k+\phi_k)$.

Using Euler formula the last can be written as, $$x(t) = X_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big\{ X_ke^{j2\pi f_k} + X_k^*e^{-j2\pi f_k} \big\} = X_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big\{ X_ke^{j2\pi f_k} \big\} + \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big\{X_k^*e^{-j2\pi f_k} \big\}$$ where $X_0 = A_0$ and $X_k = A_ke^{j\phi_k}$.

> > What I want to **prove** is given
> >
> > $$
> > a_k=
> > \begin{cases}
> > A_0, k = 0\\
> > A_ke^{j\phi_k }, k \neq 0\\
> > \end{cases}
> > $$
> >
> > the equation of signal composition can be written as:
> >
> > > $x(t) = \sum_{k=-N}^{N}a_ke^{j2\pi f_k t}$

Please let me elaborate on this by starting with what is needed to be proven. The equation $x(t) = \sum_{k=-N}^{N}a_ke^{j2\pi f_k t}$ consists of $2N+1$ terms and the expansion of this signal is:

> $$x(t) = a_{-N }e^{j2\pi f_{-N} t}+ a_{-N+1} e^{j2\pi f_{-N+1} t} + \dots + a_{-1} e^{j2\pi f_{-1} t} + a_0 e^{j2\pi f_0 t} + a_1 e^{j2\pi f_1 t} + \dots + a_{N-1} e^{j2\pi f_{N-1} t}+ a_{N} e^{j2\pi f_{N} t}$$

It is easy to see that for the right half terms we have $\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k e^{j2\pi f_k t} = \sum_k \big\{ X_ke^{j2\pi f_k} \big\}$. What is **difficult** to me is, how to prove $\sum_{k=-1}^{-N}a_{-k}^* e^{-j2\pi f_k t} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \big\{ X_{k}^*e^{-j2\pi f_k} \big\}$.

I have started by making a change of variable, i.e, $\sum_{k=1}^{N}X_k^*e^{-j2\pi f_k} = \sum_{k=-1}^{-N}X_{-k}^*e^{-j2\pi f_{-k}}$. Thus, in order to make $\sum_{k=-1}^{-N}X_{-k}^*e^{-j2\pi f_{-k}}$ equal to $\sum_{k=-1}^{-N}a_ke^{j2\pi f_k}$ as far I can see we have subsequently to prove,

> $$X_k = X_{-k}^{*} $$ and $$f_k=-f_{-k}$$

Am I right? Could you please help to understand this proof both mathematically and intuitively?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
The whole discussion was inspired by the $eq. (3.8)$ in this [doc](http://www.eas.uccs.edu/~mwickert/ece2610/lecture_notes/ece2610_chap3.pdf).

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @OfekGillon What I do not understand is how we can prove the last two equalities. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Well, the second one is from the definition of a complex Fourier series/transform. When you take $\cos f_k t $ it splits into $e^{if_k t}$ and $e^{-if_k t}$ which means they have complementary frequencies like the second equality.

Comment: For the first equality, here is a hint: $x(t)$ is real so $x(t) = x^*(t)$

Comment: @OfekGillon using the last equality is it correct to work in the following direction?  $$x(t)=x^*(t) \iff \sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathcal{Re}\{X_k e^{j2 \pi \omega_k t }\} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathcal{Re}\{X_{-k}^{*} e^{-j2 \pi \omega_k t}\} \iff \sum_{k=-N}^{N}\mathcal{Re}\{[X_k - X_{-k}^{*}] e^{j2 \pi \omega_k t }\}=0$$ 

If yes, could you please provide some extra hint to prove $X_k = X_{-k}^{*}$?

Comment: Also, as far as I understand, working on $f_k=-f_{-k}$, you suggest to use $cos f_k = \frac{1}{2}e^{jf_kt} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-jf_kt}$. Could you please elaborate a little more on this so as to reach $f_k=-f_{-k}$?

Answer (score 0):

I'll introduce a new letter: $\omega_k = 2\pi f_k $. In this case, we can write:
$$ x(t) = \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t} $$
Now:
$$ x(t) = x^* (t) $$
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t}  = \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k^* e^{-i \omega_k t} $$
Because $\omega_{-k} = -\omega_k $, we can write this as
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t}  = \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k^* e^{i \omega_{-k} t} $$
If we replace the index in the right side of the equation to be $k'=-k$ we get
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t}  = \sum_{k'=-N}^N a_{-k'}^* e^{i \omega_{k'} t} $$
But $k,k'$ are just 'dummy variables', meaning variables of summation without real meaning. We can just as well use $k$ as the index of the right side:
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t}  = \sum_{k=-N}^N a_{-k}^* e^{i \omega_{k} t} $$
Now remember that $\{ e^{i \omega_k t} \}$ are linearly independent, meaning that
$$\sum a_n e^{i\omega_n t} = \sum b_n e^{i\omega_n t} \Rightarrow \forall n : a_n=b_n $$
Here this implies 
$$a_k = a_{-k}^* $$

Comment: Thanks for the response your help is highly appreciated! But let me make some comments. I have made some changes in my question it was not 100% clear. $$ x(t) = \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{i \omega_k t} $$ is what we want to prove. So, is it the right way to start such a proof by setting this statement as the given information? Thank you again and sorry for any possible misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that. Is it given that $x(t)$ is a sum of real cosines?

Comment: Yes that is it! And in the note until $eq. (3.8)$ there is **not** other assumption for the $x(t)$, e.g., periodicity. Thanks again for the response, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, why $\omega_{-k}=-\omega_k$ ?

Comment: This is given by the expansion of cosine to complex exponents

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Sorry i didn't catch this. Did you supposed that the signal is periodic with $\omega_{k}=2\pi k f_0$ with $f_0$ the fundamental frequency and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$? Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I'm happy to help! I didn't assume such thing, just every $\cos \omega_k t$ can be represented as $\frac12 (\operatorname{exp}(i\omega_k t) + \operatorname{exp}(-i\omega_k t) )$ so by defining $\omega_{-k} = -\omega_k$ we get the result in a trivial way

Comment: Do you mean this? I found it a little strange.
$$\begin{align*}
  cos\omega_kt &= \frac{1}{2}[e^{i\omega_kt}+e^{-i\omega_kt}] \\
  \Updownarrow& \\
  cos\omega_{-k}t &= \frac{1}{2}[e^{i\omega_{-k}t}+e^{-i\omega_{-k}t}] \\
  \Updownarrow & \\
  cos(-\omega_{-k}t) &= \frac{1}{2}[e^{-i\omega_{-k}t}+e^{i\omega_{-k}t}] 
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $cos\omega_k = cos(-\omega_{-k}) \iff \omega_k = -\omega_{-k}$.